# How to cast a generic parameter?

Tags: c#

Here's what I am trying to write:

```
public void Foo<T>(T parameter) {
  otherObject.Bar<T>(parameter);
}
```

The signature of the Bar() method is:

```
public void Bar<T>(T parameter) where T: class
```

So I get a compile error because the T in Foo's signature doesn't have the same constraint. Unfortunately I can't write:

```
public void Foo<T>(T parameter) where T: class {
  otherObject.Bar<T>(parameter);
}
```

because Foo is implementing a method defined in an external interface.  Question is:

Can I somehow transpose the T within the method Foo before calling Bar.  (Note, I can be sure that T always will be a class  -  I just need to get past the compiler).

The only way I have found is using reflection but I wonder if there is a simpler trick I'm missing.

Comment: Nope; there is no other way.

Comment: What is the signature of the class of Foo<T> method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`dynamic` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) like this:

```
public void Foo<T>(T parameter)
{
    dynamic p = parameter

    otherObject.Bar(p);
}
```

What's happening is that the resolution of the call to `otherObject.Bar` is being made at run-time, because one of the parameters has a type of `dynamic`.  Assuming that `T` is a reference type, the resolution will succeed.

Granted, this ultimately uses reflection (as you've indicated), but the syntax is *probably* better than what you're using.

Of course, this will give you a run-time error in the event that `T` is *not* a class.

Comment: Thanks -  yes, your code is smaller/neater than my reflection solution, which was:  otherObject.GetType().GetMethod("Bar").MakeGenericMethod(typeof (T)).Invoke(otherObject, new object[] {parameter});

Answer (score 4):

```
public void Foo<T>(T parameter)
{
    otherObject.Bar<object>(parameter);
}
```

Comment: +1 What I was going to say.  Though I don't quite understand why it works since value types can technically also be cast to `object`.

Comment: @mellamokb Value types are not cast to `object` they are boxed.

Comment: @casperOne: If that is the case, then what is the whole point of the struct/class distinction in the first place (as far as generics are concerned)?

Comment: @mellamokb It's there so you can perform operations against the type parameter `T` such as comparisons to null, etc.  If you box a value type, that boxed value *is* an `object`, and you can perform any reference type operations you want on the `object`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly different take on casperOne's answer, using implicit interface implementation:

```
public void Foo<T>(T parameter) where T: class {
    otherObject.Bar<T>(parameter);
}

void IFoo.Foo<T>(T parameter){
    Foo((dynamic)parameter);
}
```

This allows you to include the constraint on anything that knows what specific object type they're calling `.Foo` on at compile time, while still allowing you to implement the `IFoo` interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the owner of otherObject.Bar, could you not just remove the class constraint? of that method.  Or create a new similar method without the constraint?

casperOne. I am not sure your answer is correct, as you have the class constraint on your Foo method. The question stated that this was not possible as Foo was an implementation of an external interface. For instance, the code below does not work.

```
public void Foo<T>(T param)
    {
        dynamic xx = param;

        this.Bar(param);
    }

    private void Bar<T>(T param) where T: class {

    }
```

And shows up as an error.

Comment: It would show up as an error because you aren't passing `xx` to `Bar`, you're still passing `param` from `Foo`.